# Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C829\x2dC4C1.device

Tags: uefi, multiboot

I had formatted efi partition and installed windows again. I have dual boot Windows and Linux, then I installed the grub bootloader again from a live usb using these commands:

```
 mount /dev/sda* /mnt
 mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
 mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
 mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
 mount /dev/sda* /mnt/boot/efi
 mount /mnt/hostrun
 mount --bind /run /mnt/hostrun
 chroot /mnt
 grub-install /dev/sda
 update-grub
 exit
```

Then I unmounted all of this again. When I tried to boot, I got this messages:

```
 [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C829\x2dC4C1.device.
 [DEPEND] Dependency failed for file system check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/C829-C4C1.
 [DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
 [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File System.
```

and it turns me into emergency mode. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome , Check the UUID's in your `/etc/fstab`  using  `blkid` command.

Comment: I've experienced this sort of issue before. It's because when you reformat a file system its UUID changes and your /etc/fstab is using the old UUID. As a filesystem with the old UUID no longer exists udev fails to find it and you get this error. Update the UUID in /etc/fstab using blkid and your system will manage to correctly boot again as this error will be gone.

Comment: thanks, i checked it and it was with different UUID. now it's working

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Windows formatted you EFI partition and thus its ID changed...
you need to add the *UUID* of the new partition to the one in your */etc/fstab*.
if you enter maintenance mode or have a terminal which seems you do, do this...

```
sudo blkid
```

write down the *UUID* of the EFI partition then

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

change the UUID of the old EFI partition to the one you wrote down.
if you don't know which is your EFI partition look in `sudo blkid` output. the should be a partition where it says `type=efi...`

Comment: I am fighting with a [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496298/slow-boot-time-after-cloning-disk-and-resizing-partitions) - maybe you have an advice.

Comment: Great answer. I added a uuid to /etc/fstab because I was having issues with usb permissions.  This was the wrong thing to do.  When I rebooted, Ubuntu kept returning to emergency mode.  I took your advice and opened fstab and removed the entry and Ubuntu works as expected.  Thank you. @NhlalukoG

Comment: Great answer. I had a similar problem after reformatting my swap partition, advice worked.

Comment: What if there is no efi partition, only ntfs and ext4? Anyway, had a partition in my fstab that did not exist anymore, so there is that.

Comment: You can also find the UUIDs of any partition, by using the ls -lha command in the /dev/disk/by-uuid folder

Comment: Very good answer, you're a lifesaver. Just a note for anyone else, the EFI partition might not have type=efi. In my case, the type was type=vfat.