# Slow boot time after cloning disk and resizing partitions

Tags: ubuntu, boot, fstab, gparted, timeout

I recently replaced an SSD with a larger SSD. I used [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) to clone the old disk to the new one. After that I used [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to resize the existing partition, pushing the swap partition to the end of the disk. I also updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

After successfully finishing above steps I notices that the **boot time became much longer**. I found a few similar threads (linked below) and tried what is suggested there. However, the boot time did not reduce to the amount before the disk change.

Here is my original `/etc/fstab`:

```prop
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e15b2ef7-c32d-46f5-a3a8-4bdc60285b4e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3a0c2581-52f2-4c92-9c4a-09d3f0258c05 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0 /mnt/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I already replaced the `UUID` of the `swap` partition by looking into the *blkid* command output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="e15b2ef7-c32d-46f5-a3a8-4bdc60285b4e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000d7e8b-01"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="swap" UUID="839f9d78-77b2-491d-808d-8cd551a9eeef" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000d7e8b-05"
```

I also commented out the `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-..` since I believe this was the USB stick which I booted GParted Live from. No idea why it is still defined there.

```prop
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e15b2ef7-c32d-46f5-a3a8-4bdc60285b4e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
# UUID=3a0c2581-52f2-4c92-9c4a-09d3f0258c05 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=839f9d78-77b2-491d-808d-8cd551a9eeef none            swap    sw              0       0
# /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0 /mnt/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The `/var/log/boot.log` shows the following:

```
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_USB_Flash_Disk\x2d0:0.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d52f2\x2d4c92\x2d9c4a\x2d09d3f0258c05.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/3a0c2581-52f2-4c92-9c4a-09d3f0258c05.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on PC/SC Smart Card Daemon Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
...
```

The *systemd-analyze* command tells:

```
Startup finished in 36.037s (kernel) + 10.847s (userspace) = 46.885s
graphical.target reached after 10.835s in userspace
```

What can I do to improve the boot time?

## Update

I looked into `/var/log/boot.log` again today and found this output - notice the **time-out** when searching for a device!:

```
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.    
[*     ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[**    ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[***   ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[ ***  ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[  *** ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[   ***] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[    **] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[     *] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[    **] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[   ***] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[  *** ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[ ***  ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[***   ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[**    ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[*     ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
[**    ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[***   ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[ ***  ] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d5
[  *** ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_
...
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGeneric_USB_Flash_Disk\x2d0:0.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/usb-Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a0c2581\x2d52f2\x2d4c92\x2d9c4a\x2d09d3f0258c05.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/3a0c2581-52f2-4c92-9c4a-09d3f0258c05.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on PC/SC Smart Card Daemon Activation Socket.
...
```

## Related

- [Slow boot time after resizing partitions. Editing fstab did not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843693/slow-boot-time-after-resizing-partitions-editing-fstab-did-not-work)
- [Slow boot - “a start job is running for dev-disk-by…”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by)
- [Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C829\x2dC4C1.device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471716/timed-out-waiting-for-device-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-c829-x2dc4c1-device)
- [A start job is running for dev-disk-by x2duuid-ad0b043b\x2d404c… .device (7s / 1min 30s)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956042/a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-ad0b043b-x2d404c-device-7s)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is a 'resume' file

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

which points to the UUID that is no longer found. You can modify that file to point to the correct UUID for the swap partition, and run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

See comments #16 and #17 in the following link to a bug report,

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611

---

There is a difference between your case and the case in the bug report,

- in your case you are using a swap partition
- in the case of the bug report a swap file is used (so there is no swap partition, that should be pointed to).

Comment: Yes, there is a `resume` file with a UUID which matches the UUID `3a0c2581-52f2-4c92-9c4a-09d3f0258c05` of the swap partition in the original _/etc/fstab_ which posted in my question.

Comment: Good luck with modifying that `resume` file :-)

Comment: I replaced the UUID and executed the update command. Output `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic`. I will reboot now.

Comment: I successfully rebooted. Still the _boot.log_ contains entries which indicate that `Dependency failed for ...`. The UUID referred there is the same as which I found in the `resume` file (see my question). Is _boot.log_ a good place to look for such errors or do you recommend any other system log?

Comment: Yes, `boot.log` and you can run `systemd-analyze blame` -- I understand that there are still problems, but did it improve, when you modified the `resume` file?

Comment: I think the boot time noticeable improved when I first modified the _/etc/fstab_ as described in my question. Now I cannot really tell if it changed after modifying the `resume` file. _systemd-analyze_ calculates `15.955s`. I think `46.885s` was before the change in _/etc/fstab_. Not entirely sure. The _systemd-analyze blame_ reported [this](https://pastebin.com/UYQYV1ns).

Comment: What kind of network chips/cards are there (ethernet, wifi)? Are they connected, or only one of them? -- Are you using the snaps (or some of them)? If not used, maybe you can get rid of them?

Comment: `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'`: `Ethernet: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03), Network: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300`. What is _snaps_?

Comment: You can probably save 7+ seconds off of your boot by removing the snaps and using regular apps instead.

Comment: 1. Are you using the ethernet (wired network) or the wifi or both? 2. Snaps are application programs, that are installed in a special way. They do not share the common libraries, and if I understand correctly, they can run in their own environment (at least to some degree). See [this tutorial link](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#0)

Comment: @sudodus 1. I use wifi. 2. Thank you for the explanation. I did not install any snap knowingly. 3. The boot feel like the long delay might be before Ubuntu starts - maybe Grub? How can I analyze timing there?

Comment: @JJD, 1. Several snaps come with the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. You can 'see' them with the commands `sudo lsblk -f` and `df`. The snaps are loop mounted and the mountpoints are self-explanatory. I think each snap will delay the boot one second (approximately); 2. How long is the boot time now? 3. How did you upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS? A fresh install or the Ubuntu tool `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: @sudodus 1. [I removed all but the `core` snap.](https://pastebin.com/dTid3i9M) 2. The boot time is around 15/16s - no significant change after uninstalling the snaps. I believe the delay originates from the strange USB entries as the [boot.log](https://pastebin.com/X58fbBUR) reveals. 3. I upgraded via `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: It can be difficult to troubleshoot problems after `do-release-upgrade`. I have no idea right now, but hope to come back later. Maybe you have better luck at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org), where the helpers are prepared for longer dialogues to help you try different methods, so start a thread there (at the Ubuntu Forums) with a good title and description of your problem, computer hardware and operating system (version of Ubuntu and that you have upgraded via `do-release-upgrade`).