# "Timed out waiting for device..." after disk clone with correct UUIDs

Tags: boot, dd, fstab, clonezilla

I've just cloned an SSD to a larger SSD but I'm unable to run any of my 2 linux instalations (Windows is fine).

When booting, I get this errors:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/0A91-4BD3.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0A91-4BD3.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/1c5cfcfc-7c8c-4eee-bdce-a4f6d3bafaed.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/back-portatil.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/8d455c16-9fa2-471f-b501-78903d090498.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/segun.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

but when I compare the UUIDs in `/etc/fstab` from the ones in `blkid` while chrooting from a live USB, I can see the UUIDs are correct.

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=0A91-4BD3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       2
UUID=c8bd78b7-4c4e-4941-be95-78499588fd6f       /       ext4    defaults,noatime
,discard        0       1
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777      0       0
UUID=1c5cfcfc-7c8c-4eee-bdce-a4f6d3bafaed       /mnt/back-portatil      ext4
user,auto       0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8d455c16-9fa2-471f-b501-78903d090498  /mnt/segun      auto
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0       0
```

and while in chroot I've also tried `update-grub && grub-install`, but nothing changed.

[This related issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496298/slow-boot-time-after-cloning-disk-and-resizing-partitions#496495) suggest using `sudo update-initramfs -u`, but I don't have such command.

Other related issues are caused because the UUIDs in /etc/fstab are not present in any connected disk. But that is not the case here. When the older disk is connected, the system mounts the partition with same UUID in the old disk, even when booting from the new disk, but when the old disk not present it gets stuck and seems it cannot find the partitions, even when they have the same UUID.

### Aditional info

`blkid` cropped result:

```
[...]
/dev/sda2: LABEL="bkportatil" UUID="1c5cfcfc-7c8c-4eee-bdce-a4f6d3bafaed" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="af175c98-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="segunlinux" UUID="8d455c16-9fa2-471f-b501-78903d090498" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="af175c98-03"
[...]
/dev/sdb3: UUID="803d6d97-993b-486d-8c70-9b5147d4b3bc" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ef9f577a-f8b4-7e46-9c50-11a7e124bf83"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="c8bd78b7-4c4e-4941-be95-78499588fd6f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4a009abc-f31d-d946-bdb6-5f700d12297d"
[...]
```